# If $(x-8)\cdot (x-10) = 2^y$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. then $(x,y)$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(1) If $(x-8)\cdot (x-10) = 2^y$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then the no. of ordered pairs of $(x,y)$

(2) If $x^4-6x^2+1 = 7\cdot 2^y$,where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then the no. of ordered pairs of $(x,y)$

$\underline{\bf{My\; Try}}::$ for (1) one , Given $(x-8)\cdot (x-10) = 2^y$. and $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

So $(x-8)=2^m\Rightarrow x= 8+2^m$ and $(x-10) = 2^n\Rightarrow x=10+2^n$and $m+n=y$

Now $10+2^n-8-2^m = x-x = 0\Rightarrow 2^m-2^n = 2$

Now I did not understand How can i solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Comment: $2^m = 2 (2^{n-1} + 1)$, i.e. $2^{m-1} = 2^{n-1} + 1$. This is possible only if $(m,n)=(2,1)$.

Comment: Thanks njguliyev got it, can we also write it as $2^m-2^n = 2\Rightarrow 2^{n}(2^{m-n}-1) = 2^1$, we get $n=1$ and $m-n =1 \Rightarrow m=2$, So $(m,n) = (2,1)$

Comment: Would you like to help  me for $(2)$ one, because it is not factorable, so now how can i proceed, Thanks

Comment: for (1) one i am getting only one ordered pairs i. e $(x,y) = (12,3)$  but there is one more pair which is $(x,y) = (6,3)$ so where i have make mistake.

Comment: It is also possible that $(x-8)=-2^m$ and $(x-10) = -2^n$.

Comment: @njguliyev +1, I was about to write this :)

Comment: opps I have missed that , Thanks njguliyev, kaushik  got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $2$, you have $x^4-6x^2+(1-7.2^y)=0 \Rightarrow x^2= \frac{6\pm\sqrt{32-28.2^y}}{2}$

do you now see what should be $y$???

Comment: Thanks Koushik Using yiours hint I am Getting $\displaystyle 32-28\cdot2^y\geq 0 \Rightarrow 2^y\leq \frac{32}{28}<2\Rightarrow y<1$

Comment: ayyo... what are you talking??? you are making your life very complicated... please remember $y$ has to be an integer...

Comment: No I have edited it means $ y = 0$

Comment: fine fine..  Can you now find $x$???

Comment: Thanks Kushik Iam Getting $\displaystyle x = \pm 2$.

Comment: That is fine.. :) good luck!